# "/etc/sudoers is world writable" on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, sudoers, writable

Currently, I am working on an OSX Maverick, and I can't use `sudo` command in Terminal.

---

> My-Mac:~ phucnd$ sudo
>
> sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
>
> sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: can you do `ls -al /etc/sudoers;id` and give us the output? You may need to do `man chmod` to learn how to change the permissions on files. If the file isn't owned by you, you may need to find another way to login as root to change the permissions on the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open Disk Utility, select you disk and click "Repair Disk Permissions"

[image]

Comment: 2022: Using "First aid" worked for me

Answer (score 16):

Finder → Go → Go to folder:

and enter `/etc/sudoers` and push `Go` button.

Right click on the `sudoers` and change ther permission.

Comment: The following file permissions worked for me:

System: Read & Write
Wheel: Read Only
Everyone: Read Only

Answer (score 7):

1.Enable root user:
System Preferences -> Users&Groups -> Login options -> Network Account Server -> Join -> Open Directory Utility -> Edit(menu) -> Enable Root User

2.switch to root,change /etc/sudoers permissions
$su
$chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

Comment: Great trick; thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Finder -> Go -> Go to folder

and enter /etc/sudoers and push Go button.
Right click on the sudoers -> click on get info -> change permission to:
System: Read & Write 
Wheel: Read Only 
Everyone: Read Only

Lock it and open a terminal and try again.

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Just use these commands below under any terminal will do:

1. $ su
2. $ chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `/etc/ directory:
   [image]
2. Right click on `sudoers` > Get Info
3. Click lock icon
4. Set permissions as follows:

[image: sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable]
5. Try running `sudo ls` and see if you get any errors. If you get an error about `sudoers.d` just delete that folder if its empty.